# Plugins modal não estão funcionando no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, modal, plugin-wordpress

Tenho uma página em Wordpress, instalei vários plugins para exibição de modal na home mas nenhum deles está exibindo o modal. Testei em outra página wordpress que tenho e funcionou normal. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Sem trechos de código fica difícil oferecer alguma ajuda

Comment: Utilizei os mesmos plugins em duas páginas distintas, mas em uma funcionou e na outra, não. Tem alguma coisa a ver com banco ou a hospedagem?

Answer (score 0):

A causa mais comum de erros desse tipo é o uso de temas que não implementam as funções `wp_head()` dentro da tag `<header>` ou `wp_footer()` no final do documento.

Confira se a página que você está testando tem essas duas funções (elas podem estar em arquivos diferentes, mas precisam ser chamadas em toda as páginas).

Comment: Foram implementadas. Pode ser alguma coisa com o banco?

Comment: Acho pouco provavel. Voce consegue encontrar o modal vendo o HTML? Ou ele nem chega a ser adicionado na pagina?

Comment: Ele nem chega a carregar na página, nem aparece. Achei que fosse incompatibilidade com a versão do WP, mas instalei o mesmo plugin em outro cliente e funcionou normal.